# Create custom complex xml shape android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml, android-drawable

How do I create shapes like in an attachment, and use them as backgroungs for TextViews?
Also please get me a link to the guides on creating custom complex shapes

[attachment link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvpEg.png)

Answer (score 0):

To Create custom shape, Here is Github project- [ShapeOfView](https://github.com/florent37/ShapeOfView)

From ShapeOfView you can use `com.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.DiagonalView`

Dependancy : `implementation 'com.github.florent37:shapeofview:(lastest version)'`

Try below code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <com.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.DiagonalView
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:shape_diagonal_angle="-10"
            app:shape_diagonal_position="right">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Text1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_left_side"/>
        </com.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.DiagonalView>
        <com.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.DiagonalView
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:shape_diagonal_angle="-10"
            app:shape_diagonal_position="left">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Text2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_right_side"/>
        </com.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.DiagonalView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

The output for above code is:
[image]

I hope it works for you.